# SnowSQL fails with "The library Security could not be found" after upgrading to mac Big Sur

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowsql

After upgrading to macOS Big Sur my snowsql scripts all fail with "The Library Security could not be found"

```
$ snowsql -q "select 1 x"
User: me
Password: XXX
The library Security could not be found
If the error message is unclear, enable logging using -o log_level=DEBUG and see the log to find out the cause. Contact support for further help.
Goodbye!
```

This reminds me of an issue I ran into with the snowflake-connector-python library involving oscrypto library being used instead of openssl when I upgraded to macOS Catalina several months ago, the issue is documented here: https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-python/issues/235

When I first saw the issue today I was running an earlier version of SnowSQL (1.1.something) then I upgraded to 1.2.9 and got the same error. I tried adding the "-o log_level=DEBUG" to the SnowSQL command line but it didn't output any additional information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you try the following steps?

- Move the User's snowsql directory to a backup:
  mv ~/.snowsql ~/.snowsql.prebigsur
- Move the SnowSQL application to the trash from the Applications folder.
- Make sure "/Applications/SnowSQL.app" is gone.
- Then download and install the latest SnowSQL from the darwin repo (https://sfc-repo.snowflakecomputing.com/snowsql/bootstrap/1.2/darwin_x86_64/index.html)

Comment: I have the same issue with DBT connecting to Snowflake and I cant find a solution. Any ideas?

Comment: @Cristian I had the same problem. My python version is updated to 3.9 after installing Big Sur. Unfortunately dbt-snowflake does not work with python 3.9 yet.  https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-python/issues/562  I am using dbt with python 3.8 without any problems on Big Sur.

Comment: @Cristian Linking back to [this issue](https://github.com/fishtown-analytics/dbt/issues/2933) -  I had success with requiring `oscrypto==1.2.1`

Answer (score 5):

I was running into the same thing and the only help I can find was this thread and a few unanswered github issues.

For me, I'm using SQLAlchemy to connect to Snowflake. Worked just fine until I upgraded to Big Sur.

After digging through the code, it looks like things were stemming from `oscrypto 1.20` for me. It was specifically calling our the `_security_cffi.py` and around line 239, they were doing something like this:

```
Security = find_library('Security')
```

I went to their [page](https://pypi.org/project/oscrypto/) and saw that there was a new version `1.21`

After downloading it, the code changed to this:

```
security_path = '/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security'

Security = ffi.dlopen(security_path)
```

Now I'm able to run my queries against snowflake without issue.

Comment: Specifically, `pip install --upgrade oscrypto` worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

After reading @mwlilson 's answer I tried the following and it seems to have worked. For me the error was arising when I tried to use the `dropbox` python module.

```
# Solution
pip uninstall oscrypto
pip install oscrypto
```

Comment: I don't think duplicating an existing answer does anyone any good.

Comment: this is a nice tl;dr answer

Answer (score 3):

For me oscrypto==1.2.0 worked on macOS Big Sur 11.5.1

1. Like @Gokhan Atil's answer, I installed the latest version of [SnowSQL](https://sfc-repo.snowflakecomputing.com/snowsql/bootstrap/1.2/darwin_x86_64/index.html)
2. `pip uninstall oscrypto`
3. `pip install oscrypto==1.2.1`

Answer (score 0):

This is what fixed it on mine.

1. Download the latest snowsql installation from the snowflake website.
   [snowflake downloads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62OVQ.png)

2. Run installation
3. Verify the file $HOME/.snowsql/config contains your database connection settings.
4. Write the config file to disk even if you made no changes.

After installation, I continued to see the same error until I re-saved the same config file. Perhaps there is a library cache for snowsql that does not refresh until it notices changes in the config?  That fixed the problem. (Not sure if the re-installation was absolutely necessary, but it's working now).