# Can no longer use Snowflake connector with Big Sur: error The library Security could not be found

Tags: python-3.x, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I just upgraded to Big Sur and can no longer connect to snowflake. Getting the following error: The library Security could not be found

I've followed these steps and the issue is not resolved. Anyone have another work around?

[SnowSQL fails with "The library Security could not be found" after upgrading to mac Big Sur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65012259/snowsql-fails-with-the-library-security-could-not-be-found-after-upgrading-to#_=)_

Comment: Can you try upgrading **oscrypto** to latest version? **pip install --upgrade git+https://github.com/wbond/oscrypto**

Comment: Thanks so much, Sergiu. It got rid of the Security library issue but now am getting this error. "Failed to execute request: 'SSLSocket' object has no attribute 'connection'"

Comment: Can we see the log and the stacktrace of that SSLSocket error?

Comment: Given that the OS is unsupported, I doubt you are going to get this to work and, even if you "technically" got it to work, would you trust that it was operating correctly? If you just want to hack it for the intellectual challenge then fine but trying to use it for actual work is not a good idea

Answer (score 0):

macOS 11 (Big Sur) is not supported for SnowSQL:

[SnowSQL Documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowsql.html)

```
Operating System    Supported Versions
================    ==================
Linux               CentOS 6, 7, 8
                    Redhat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) 6, 7, 8
                    Ubuntu 16.04, 18.04 (Support for Ubuntu 14.04 is deprecated.)
macOS               10.13, 10.14, 10.15
Microsoft Windows   Windows 8, 8.1, 10 (Support for Microsoft Windows 7 is deprecated.)
                    Windows Server 2012, 2016, 2019
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually re-install oscrypto as Sergiu mentioned - to version 1.2.1.  This should fix the problem.